# Filtering and deleting data using a modifiable date

Tags: vba, excel

I want to filter by a date specified in a cell (that a user can change) then delete the entire rows and unfilter. I get an *object required error* on the **`Set = LastRow`** section.

```
 Sub Button_Delete_Rows()

 Dim CuttoffDate As Date
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim rng As Range

 Set CutoffDate = Sheets("PL Refresh").Range("K3").Value

 Set LastRow = Sheets("Data").Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 Set rng = Sheets("Data").Range("F")
 With rng
     .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & "CutoffDate"
     .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
 End With

 rng.AutoFilterMode = False

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the keyword `Set` on a simple type, it is only used for Objects (Workbook, Worksheet, Range, ...).

`CutoffDate = Sheets("PL Refresh").Range("K3").Value`
and

`LastRow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Sheets("Data").Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row`

are sufficient.

EDIT: I edited lastrow, because `ws` is an object undefined. Maybe something that stayed in your code although you don't have that object anymore.

Comment: but I have removed it and get a debug error on the line above now

Comment: @RosePetal17 Date isn't an object, so just get rid of the `Set` too! ;)

Comment: thank you, but any ideas why now its bringing up the 'object required' error again on the LastRow = Sheets line? Sorry I have been trying to get this to work for ages :/

Comment: @RosePetal17 You got rid of the `Set` before `CutOffDate` and you got rid of the `Set` before `LastRow` and it still gives you the error?

Comment: yeh the code is now;    
 Sub Button_Delete_Rows()
 
 Dim CuttoffDate As Date
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim rng As Range
 
 CutoffDate = Sheets("PL Refresh").Range("K3").Value
 
 LastRow = Sheets("Data").Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 Set rng = Sheets("Data").Range("F")
 With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & "CutoffDate"
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    
    rng.AutoFilterMode = False
    
 End Sub

Comment: Ah, no wonder it fails. You have an object `ws` in the definition that does not exist. I alter my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you @EngJon I didn't spot this error! but in your amendment it doesn't specify the "data" sheet or range "F".   would I put LastRow = Sheets("Data").Range("F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row??

Comment: Not exactly. I just inserted my default solution for last rows. I will edit my answer once again to provide the last row on that sheet in column F.

Comment: @EngJon I am sorry to be a pain here and what you amended before works great however... now the line below it now run-time errors 1004 Set rng = Sheets("Data").Range("F")  I have tried with and without the 'set'. any ideas?

Comment: What is rng supposed to cover? If it should be the whole column F then in that row change `Range("F")` to `Range("F:F")`